# FindRoot: Power: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered

Tags: equation-solving, system

I am trying to solve the problem below with `FindRoot`. At first it works well, but when I change the constants in my equation the solver returns with the message:

> `FindRoot: Power: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.`

What does this means? Is there no solution for the system with the new values in `e2`?

Also when I put `M -> 10` in `data`, another message appears for `icmsol1`:

> `FindRoot:Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.`

```
data = {M -> 1, To -> 280.5, T∞ -> 254}

μv = {3.9300, 7.3663, 10.6438, 13.8624, 17.0535, 20.2295, 23.3965, 26.5574, 29.7144, 32.8684}

fi = (To (Sin[μ[j][0]] - Cos[μ[j][0]] μ[j][0]))/(T∞ μ[j][0]^2)

Ni[τ_, j_] = Integrate[Sin[μ[j][τ]*x]^2, {x, 0, 1}]

fr = T1^3
f2 = 1/T1

e1 = Table[(mi*Cos[mi] + ((1*fr - 1 - 0.5*f2) /. T1 -> Sum[Sin[μ[j][0]]*(1/Ni[0, j])*fi, {j, M /. data}])*Sin[mi] == 0) /. mi -> μ[i][0], {i, M /. data}]

e2 = Table[(mi*Cos[mi] + ((0.00122275*fr - 0.879355 - 1.67153*f2) /. T1 -> Sum[Sin[μ[j][0]]*(1/Ni[0, j])*fi, {j, M /. data}])*Sin[mi] == 0) /. mi -> μ[i][0], {i, M /. data}]

CImsys = Table[{μ[i][0], μv[[i]]}, {i, M /. data}]

icmsol1 = FindRoot[e1 /. data, CImsys]

icmsol2 = FindRoot[e2 /. data, CImsys]
```

Comment: It means something was divided by zero in the course of trying to find the root.  You might need a better starting point for the root search.  You also might want to inspect your functions (if you haven't) to make sure they look right.

Comment: Thank you Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that for `e2` your solution is zero and your function blows up at `μ[1][0] == 0`.  This can be seen if we plot.

```
Plot[Evaluate[(e2 /. data)[[1, 1]]], {μ[1][0], -10, 10}]
```

[image]

From the plot it looks like your root is at zero.  If you try to verify with a straight calculation:

```
(e2 /. data)[[1, 1]] /. μ[1][0] -> 0;
```

you will get an infinite expression which is why FindRoot was unsuccessful.  If you take the limit, however:

```
Limit[(e2 /. data)[[1, 1]], μ[1][0] -> 0]
(*0.*)
```

You get verification that the root is zero.

For greater values of `M`, I suggest you use exact numbers in your given data, and increase the WorkingPrecision for FindRoot.  That should solve your convergence problems.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Your answer was very helpful. I think there is something wrong with my equation, I was not expecting only one root for it.